# How to find number of style classes defined in a CSS file

Tags: css, stylesheet

How do you find number of style classes defined in a CSS file? I need to clean my stylesheet. Please tell me of any good clean-up solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried to get count of '{', worked

Answer (score 1):

Try Dust-me, a Firefox add-one. It shows you all unused CSS selectors. https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/dust-me-selectors/

Comment: hi Hussein, As I do not have site map and my application is bigger, I could not use it. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Maybe i didn't understand the question. How is number of styles and cleanup related. Why is it important to find the number of classes in your stylesheet. What are you trying to do.

Comment: Here is my exact problem. I though of cleaning up the stylesheet. [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5447741/how-to-define-more-than-one-stylesheet-in-adf-framework[link]